# Is there a tool to open a text-file directly from a remote (WM) device?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-mobile, activesync

When I browse the files on a remote Windows Mobile device using ActiveSync, I regularly want to view the contents of txt files (application log files, etc.). Windows XP is not able to open these files directly from the device, so I have to copy them to my local disk first before I can open them.

Is there a tool for WinXP that allows me to open the files in one click, rather then have to copy them first?

**Update**
I am specifically looking for a desktop-based tool, not a tool that runs on the device. The reason is that I frequently hard-reset the device and I do not want to have to reinstall the tool each time I do that.

Comment: Could you upgrade to Vista (or Windows 7) at all? They behave as you desire...

Comment: @Rowland I know, but unfortunately that is not an option, since I intend to install it on my PC at work, where I cannot upgrade the OS.

Comment: Well, it'd be a business case to justify the upgrade -- just thought I'd check the obvious. Are you able to use a virtualised development environment instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try [WM5torage](http://www.modaco.com/index.php?automodule=downloads&showfile=1702): a tool that allows to use your PDA as a regular USB mass storage device (or a flash drive if you want). Quick way to download it is go [here](http://www.freewarepocketpc.net/get-wm5torage.html) and click 'Mirror download': forum on which it's hosted won't allow  downloading of files for anonymous users.

Comment: This might do what I want, problem is: I use it during development of Windows Mobile software and I clean the mobile devices regularly. It is too cumbersome to reinstall the tool on the mobile device every time. I was hoping for a desktop-based tool that can work with any connected WM device.